# Why does a QuadraticBezierSegment render differently between drawing with a line and animating with a DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry?

Tags: wpf, animation, path, bezier

I have defined a `QuadraticBezierSegment` object as the `Data` property of a `Path` object:

```
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="450,250" IsClosed="False">
                <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="245,-50" Point2="0,25" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

It is shown below in red, and shows the curve that I expected.:

[image]

However, when this same curve is used in a path animation, the path of the animated element is NOTHING like the path of the line shown in the image above. [Please note that this is only part of the animation that I've been creating.]

```
<Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="#FF01ADEF" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" BeginTime="0:0:3">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:1.5" 
                            AccelerationRatio="0.2">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="450,250" IsClosed="False">
                                        <QuadraticBezierSegment 
                                            Point1="245,-50" Point2="0,25" />
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" 
                        BeginTime="0:0:3" >
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:1.5" From="400" To="0" 
                            DecelerationRatio="0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

Does anybody know why that is and what I have to do to make the animation path actually follow the path shown in the image?

Comment: You probably forgot to set the [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath.source(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DoubleAnimationUsingPath.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for uploading my image... I can't see the benefit of not allowing new users to upload their images... it just makes it more awkward for everyone else to view them.
And thanks for the quick response, but what should I set the `Source` property to? The linked page doesn't provide much of a clue.

Comment: Click on the [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pathanimationsource(v=vs.110).aspx) of the property. You can set Source to either X, Y or Angle. Are you sure you understand what a DoubleAnimationUsingPath exactly does?

Comment: Well, I _thought_ I did... but setting the `Source` property to `Y` (as it's animating the `Canvas.Top` property) still doesn't make it follow the expected path. Ahhhh... I've just used an additional `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` for the `Cavas.Left` property and set the `Source` property to the default `X` value, and now it seems to work. So many thanks. If you'd like to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: As a note, instead of animating Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top by two separate animations, you may also animate the Matrix property of a MatrixAnimation in the Ellipse's RenderTransform property. Assign a MatrixTransform to RenderTransform and use `Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Matrix"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add another `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` to animate the `Canvas.Left` property and set the `Source` property on both `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` elements, to specify whether they should use the `X` and `Y` parts of the `QuadraticBezierSegment` object. This is what the code looks like now:

```
<Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="#FF01ADEF" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                        BeginTime="0:0:3">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:1.5"
                                AccelerationRatio="0.2" Source="Y">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="400,200" IsClosed="False">
                                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="245,-50"
                                            Point2="0,0" />
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                        BeginTime="0:0:3" >
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:1.5" 
                            AccelerationRatio="0.2" Source="X">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="400,200" IsClosed="False">
                                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="245,-50"
                                            Point2="0,0" />
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```