# Drawing image into a Window and update it

Tags: c#, wpf, draw

I have an unsafe class that generate a Bitmap which is converted to ToImageSource in order to draw into a Window. The Bitmap itself contains a sinusoidal text which is frequently updated and I want to it "move" from the left to the right (marquee style?). Anyway it works just fine in a WinForm but I'm stuck with the WPF Window.

Here are some code samples:

```
public AboutWindow()
{
    InheritanceBehavior = InheritanceBehavior.SkipAllNow;
    InitializeComponent();
    Initialize();
}

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    drawingContext.DrawImage(bitmapRender.WindowBitmap, drawingArea);

    if (!worker.IsBusy) 
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // BackgroundWorker in charge of updating the bitmap
}

void DispatcherTimerRender_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) => InvalidateVisual();
```

My issues are: there is nothing displayed on the Window and the DispatchedTimer that calls InvalidateVisual() leads to this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.'

I have looked at other threads and I'm aware that WPF is a retained drawing system but I would love to achieve it anyway.

Any suggestion about the "best" way to achieve this?

Any useful explanation/link would be very much appreciated.

[Edit]

```
<Window x:Class="CustomerManagement.View.AboutWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d" Height="450" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Width="800" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
        <Image Width="800" Height="450" Source="{Binding 'Image'}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Because as I stated, I'm new to WPF and learning it...

Comment: WPF has paths and animations. You don't need to render individual images like Winforms. You can't get a smooth animation this way. In fact, you could probably generate a Path object from the points you calculate and display them directly on your window. Check [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview).

Comment: BTW **don't** look at the example that specifies a path with Bezier curve in a couple of lines of XML :P . Any element's parameters can be animated too, which means you can animate curves just with XAML, as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369396/why-does-a-quadraticbeziersegment-render-differently-between-drawing-with-a-line)

Comment: Text can follow paths too, which means you could display your text along an animated path. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your links. I did a bit a basic drawing. Aim is to do a scrolling string with a sinusoidal effect goes goest from left to right and loop when it reaches the end of the string. This is now perfectly working. But if you have some WPF snippet to achieve this I'd readily give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an Image element that has its Source property bound to an ImageSource property in a view model. This is the "standard" way, based on the MVVM architectural pattern, and therefore the "best" way - in my opinion.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
```

The view model could look like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ImageSource image;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set
        {
            image = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));
        }
    }
}
```

and an instance of it would be assigned to the DataContext of the window:

```
public AboutWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

---

For testing it, the code below performs a slide show of image files in a directory. You may as well assign any other ImageSource - e.g. a DrawingImage - to the Image property.

```
var imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(..., "*.jpg");
var index = -1;
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    if (++index < imageFiles.Length)
    {
        vm.Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageFiles[index]));
    }
    else
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
};

timer.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your code sample which is very much more neat than mine, I just tried it but I'm getting this exception : Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject." with PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));

Comment: In ViewModel class, on  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image))); and yes dispatcherTimerRender = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(1) };
            dispatcherTimerRender.Tick += DispatcherTimerRender_Tick;
            dispatcherTimerRender.Start();

Comment: Did you perhaps create the view model or the DispatcherTimer in a background thread?

Comment: Well I removed the BackgroundWorker which was the problem. Instead I'm updating the Bitmap with the DispatcherTimer Tick. It now "works" but there is nothing displayed on screen, while If I save the image, the output is correct.

Comment: I'm the XAML file I'm only using <Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown"><Image ...</Grid> but that should not affect anything, shouldn't it ?

Comment: <Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
        <Image Name="Image" Width="800" Height="450" Source="{Binding 'Image'}" />
    </Grid> If I step into the code everything seems fine as for the update.

Comment: I only have a DataContext in Window constructor, same as the example you provided.

Comment: the only difference with your code is the test. My code is : void DispatcherTimerRender_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sinusoidalScrollingText?.UpdateBitmap();
            viewModel.Image = sinusoidalScrollingText.WindowBitmap;
        }

Comment: Lemme give me shot. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: It's looping (copied your test and specified a folder with jpg). It's looping through all of them but I can see nothing on screen

Comment: I added the XAML, the code behind is simalar to what you posted. Issue is the same if I loop through pictures or use the class which generates / updates the bitmap.

Comment: Sure you have assigned the DataContext of AboutWindow, not MainWindow? Check the Output Window in Visual Studio. Are there any data binding error messages?

Comment: Resharper is telling me that it cannot resolve symbol 'Image' in XAML due to unknown data context